# Safecracker file path

Tags: safecracker, safecracker-file

I have a safecracker file displaying the URL twice:

```
 <a href="{contract}" target="_blank">View Contract</a>
```

It's displaying like so:

http://figdoylestown.com/figdoylestown.com/uploads/web-08.jpg

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at your upload locations setup. It looks like something may be set incorrectly for the location's URL. (This could be setup through the CP or in your config.php)

Comment: Hi Jeremy - I'm using the same upload directory for lots of other parts of the site and there are no issues.

Comment: Well that's odd indeed then. Are these uploads coming from a Safecracker form? Or are they uploaded through the CP? The only thing is if you're using relative paths, it may be saving the paths differently somehow.

Comment: You might also look directly in the database to see what data is being stored.